# Adding signingCertificateV2 attribute to SignedCms

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, signature, digital

```
    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.5"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString()));
    
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);
    CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(cert);

    cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
    cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
    cmsSigner.SignerIdentifierType = SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber;


    Pkcs9AttributeObject att = new Pkcs9AttributeObject();
    AsnEncodedData data = new AsnEncodedData(new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(cert.RawData));

    cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.UtcNow));
    //cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9ContentType());
    //cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9MessageDigest());
   
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedCms.Encode());
```

I have used this code to sign a document and this code is working fine but my problem is that there is another requirement needed to add "SigningCertificateV2" attribute as a signed attribute...

I have already added ContentType, MessageDigest and SigningTime. But i dont know how to add "SigningCertificateV2" attribute.. (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47)

Can You please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

*(It seems this question's been sitting unanswered for more than a year and a half, so I really hope Asharf managed to comply with the new requirement somehow. There's been more than 300 views though, so hopefully a late answer would still be helpful.)*

The types in [`System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) do not provide support for the full range of attributes defined by various Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) specs like [CMS Advanced Electronic Signatures (CAdES)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5126) and [Enhanced Security Services Update (ESSCertIdUpdate)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5035), but only for the most commonly used attribs like `Pkcs9ContentType`, `Pkcs9MessageDigest`, `Pkcs9SigningTime`, etc.

Specifically, there's no "strongly-typed" wrapper around the `SigningCertificatev2` attribute, defined by ESSCertIdUpdate ([RFC 5035](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)). In that case, one has to use the "generic" `CryptographicAttributeObject` type and construct the ASN.1 encoded data for the attribute "by hand", that is, concoct a raw byte[], typically by using `System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter` (and thoroughly reading the relevant RFC -- that's always a good idea, btw).

Defining a wrapper for the SigningCertificatev2 attrib requires a fair amount of code as several other related RFC types like `ESSCertIDv2` and `PolicyInformation` need also be defined.

Luckily, there's a well-known open-source software project that already does exactly that -- it can be used for "inspiration" ;-). That's NuGet, and specifically the [NuGet client](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/).

*(I know link-only answers are frowned upon on SO, but I guess a link-mostly answer is better than no answer, so here goes...).*

Here are the links to the relevant parts in the GutHub repo.

- [CreateSigningCertificateV2()](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f24bad0668193ce21a1db8cabd1ce95ba509c7f0/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/Signing/Utility/AttributeUtility.cs#L251) in `AttributeUtility`
- The [SigningCertificateV2](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f24bad0668193ce21a1db8cabd1ce95ba509c7f0/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/Signing/Signatures/SigningCertificateV2.cs#L21) type itself.
- The [EssCertIdV2](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f24bad0668193ce21a1db8cabd1ce95ba509c7f0/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/Signing/Signatures/EssCertIdV2.cs#L30) type, used by SigningCertificateV2.

The NuGet client's attribute implementation can't be used directly as a library, but it should provide a nice guideline about how to construct the PKCS attribute.